# html: Accessing a mouse event from onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, events

I know that I can access a mouse event if I assign the mouse listener with js:

```
myElement.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(e.pageX))
```

My question is: is it possible to access the mouse event when assigning the listener by html attribute?

```
<div onclick="alert('where is the mouse event?')"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The onclick will be evaluated as the inside of a function, and that function will have an argument of the event, so you can do it like this:

```html
<div onclick="console.log(arguments[0].pageX)">text</div>
```

But you really, really shouldn't. Always attach listeners with Javascript instead of HTML-inline-eval. Code will be easier to write, easier to read, safer, and more maintainable.

Comment: I see... Until now I thought that the 2 ways were kind of equivalent.
It looks like I was wrong.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can check that by passing `event` to the function:

```js
function checkEvent(e, msg){
  console.log(e.type, 'event has been fired.');
  console.log(e.pageX);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="checkEvent(event, 'where is the mouse event?')" >Click My Div</div>
```

Comment: Works great with divs and most other tags.

Strangely, when I apply the exact same thing to an svg element I was getting "event is not defined". It looks like this is tag-specific...